# Google Play publish app with the same name

Tags: android, google-play

I have published an android app in the store, however, we lost the keystore, when I unpublish the current app and try to republish another app with the same name I've got a message saying that I couldn't publish an app with the same name, is there a manipulation to do ?

Thanks :)

Comment: did you tried to change package name?

Comment: Have u changed the appId ?

Comment: You can have multiple apps in the play store with the same display name, but they have to have different package names (and the play store won't actually allow a second app with the same package name as another even to be uploaded)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I have changed the appid, however, the problem occurs when I create the app in google play, I still have my app that is unpublished, I want to create another app with another appID but the same name, it says that I can't have the same name. I am not requested to load the apk

Answer (score 0):

Every application on Google Play needs to have a separate application id (like `com.company.awesomeapp`). So if you lost your keystore and can't upload the application with the id you had before, you will have to change the id (say, `com.company.awesomeapp2`).

One small note, now the application id is not the same as the application package. So you may continue to use the old application package internally (for the source files and in the manifest), but you need to change the `applicationId` in `gradle.build` to something new. If you reference the application id somewhere in the manifest, you can use a placeholder: `${applicationId}`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for my problem was to rename the previous application and create an app with the same name.
I obviously had to change the app id also

Answer (score 0):

Even though your old app is not available for download anymore, the Play Store still requires a different `applicationId`, because some users might still have the old app installed on their devices (it still may be 'supported' in the sense that users can buy in app purchases etc.), and it's the Android OS that explicitly denies installation of packages with the same name, and allows updates when the id and certificate is the same.

You could imagine a situation where you delete an app from the play store, and if it would allow creating a new one with the same `applicationId`, and someone got hold of your keystore and certificate, that person could upload a completely different app and trigger updates to users with your old app. Now, that would be very bad and simple solution is just to not allow same `applicationId`s.